# How do I get the GridView Control to use post backs for paging inside an update panel?

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView Control that for other functionality has to be inside an update panel. The site is using the Ajax Control Toolkit and the "EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks" property on the Grid is set to false. However, when I execute a paging call it is still doing it as a callback instead of a postback. How do I fix this and get the paging calls to fire as a postback?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in the triggers collection of the update panel to create a trigger for your gridview that is a full postback instead of asynchronous.  This is especially useful when there are some update panels inside others that you might only want to update at certain times but not others.  You can also change the code-behind to tell it when to do the update.